# Can I create the effect of useGridApiRef() with mui/x-data-grid non pro version?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am working on a material ui data grid table within a larger react web app. The table's header does not have any sorting or other interactable features. So I want to prevent the user from accessing it via keyboard navigation.

I found a relevant thread on MUI's github page, but the [code example](https://codesandbox.io/s/datagridpro-v5-quick-start-forked-y1jhq?file=/src/App.tsx) uses datagrid's pro version. The useGridApiRef() appears to be a data grid pro-only feature, but is it possible to mimmic it's effect without the pro version?

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled on this today and I think it might give you a place to start. It's fairly simply but seems to work.

[Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/66726455material-ui-get-all-rows-from-datagrid-lpcyc?file=/src/App.js:0-2272)